# js узнать сколько лет прошло от заданной даты. Появляются лишние 60лет

Tags: javascript, дата, datetime

```
const date1 = new Date(2000, 12, 4);
console.log(new Date(new Date().getTime() - date1.getTime()).getYear());
```

Пытаюсь получить сколько лет прошло от заданной даты, до текущего момента. Но почему-то результат выдается на 60 лет больше, чем должно быть.

Comment: getYear возвращает год указанной даты, если верить документации. Но вычитание даёт не дату, а интервал между датами в миллисекундах. Так что надо не getYear применять, а тупо делить на количество миллисекунд в году.

Comment: а не проще взять год, который сейчас, и отнять от него год, который Вам нужен? например: `2021 - 2000 = 21`))

Comment: @Akina Логично, спасибо!

Comment: @Август Лол. Да, Вы правы! Что-то я совсем, пойду прогуляюсь лучше....

Comment: @Август А хотя нет. Мне нужно не просто года отнимать. А именно "сейчас" от конкретной даты (месяц и день важны)

Comment: @Gelloiss, я как раз писал комментарий, что я мог ошибаться, если Вам, допустим, нужно узнать полные года возраста человека, но Вы меня опередили). ну ответ `@Akina` вполне приемлемый, используйте его решение

Comment: Выделите месяц и день и сравните отдельно. Если месяц больше, или месяц равен, а день больше - отнимите ещё один год.

Answer (score 0):

Этот вопрос эквивалентен вычислению возраста. Ответ есть, например, тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060004/calculate-age-given-the-birth-date-in-the-format-yyyymmdd

Приведу пример (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7091965/5122436):

```js
function getAge(dateString) {
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
        age--;
    }
    return age;
}
```

Comment: Зачем использовать var?

Comment: @Gelloiss это копипаст решения со stackoverflow (english). А вообще, `var` совместим с любой версией javascript (ecmascript) (в отличии от `let` и `const`)

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще вот так вычислять количество полных лет...

```js
let d1 = new Date(2000, 12, 4);
let d2 = new Date();
d1 = d1.toISOString().split('T')[0].replaceAll('-', '')
d2 = d2.toISOString().split('T')[0].replaceAll('-', '')
const val = Math.trunc((d2 - d1) / 10000)
console.log(val)
```